# Retrieving the name of a particular column of a table in R

Tags: r, identity-column

I have the next data frame (matrix):

```
> Table
   Clima Crecimiento
1      1         350
2      1         375
3      1         360
4      1         400
5      1         380
6      2         500
7      2         530
8      2         520
9      2         550
10     2         545
```

I would like to know the command to retrieve the name of the first column exclusively (Clima), as it is a categorical column and I need to introduce it in a code I am preparing to ease discriminant function analysis.

I tryed using names(), colnames[.1], with no succeed. I suppose I am near to the solution, however, some missing code is needed in order to solve what I request.

Thanks

Comment: `colnames(Table)[1]`

Comment: Is there any possibility Pascal to retrieve the name of the categorical column automatically? I mean, depending on where it is (first, second,... n column), to retrieve its name independently to its position.

Comment: Is your categorical column of a different type? (Say, for example, `factor` instead of `numeric`?)

Comment: To complement the above comment - if there is one single column that has distinct type e.g. factor, then you can use `is.factor()` to determine the position of column and then get `colnames()`

Comment: Dear A. Val. Could you explain further with my example? In my table, Clima is the factor. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to get the number of the column without the quotation marks?